# How do I make a pygame trivia question appear in the entry widget

Tags: pygame, python-3.7, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to create a trivia game using pygame. The first trivia question appears on the entry widget. However, I want the second question to appear in the entry widget once the first question has been answered correctly. 
Also If at any point the player selects a wrong answer I want the game to exit/end.

Apologies for the long line of code. I would have loved to put the question and answer in a text file instead of coding them directly inside python, but I obviously don't know how to do go about it.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import pygame as py
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

py.init()
py.mixer.init()
root=Tk()
root.title("Who Wants To Be A Millionaire")
root.geometry=('1352x625+0+0')
root.configure(background ='black')
abc= Frame(root, bg = 'black')
abc.grid()

abc1= Frame(root, bg = 'black', bd=20, width=900, height=600)
abc1.grid(row=0, column=0)
abc2= Frame(root, bg = 'black', bd=20, width=452, height=600)
abc2.grid(row=0, column=1)

abc1a= Frame(abc1, bg = 'black', bd=20, width=900, padx=110, height=200)
abc1a.grid(row=0, column=0)
abc1b= Frame(abc1, bg = 'black', bd=20, width=900, height=200)
abc1b.grid(row=1, column=0)
abc1c= Frame(abc1, bg = 'black', bd=20, width=900, height=200)
abc1c.grid(row=2, column=0)

#===========================================Trivia Questions==============================================

question1 = StringVar()
question2 = StringVar()
question3 = StringVar()
question4 = StringVar()
question5 = StringVar()
question6 = StringVar()
question7 = StringVar()
question8 = StringVar()
question9 = StringVar()
question10 = StringVar()
question11 = StringVar()
question12 = StringVar()
question13 = StringVar()
question14 = StringVar()
question15 = StringVar()


choice1 = StringVar()
choice2 = StringVar()
choice3 = StringVar()
choice4 = StringVar()


question1.set("What's the capital of Nigeria")
choice1.set('Mongoria')
choice2.set('Cairo')
choice3.set('Accra')
choice4.set('Abuja')


question2.set(" Which one of the color can be found in US National Flag")
choice1.set("Green")
choice2.set('Red')
choice3.set('Orange')
choice4.set('Yelow')

question3.set("What is 5000 x 110")
choice1.set("55,110")
choice2.set('56,100')
choice3.set('50,000')
choice4.set('55,000')

question4.set("Whitney Houston died in which year")
choice1.set("2013")
choice2.set('2010')
choice3.set('2012')
choice4.set('2011')

question5.set("How many countries are there in Africa")
choice1.set("32")
choice2.set('43')
choice3.set('45')
choice4.set('30')


#===========================================Text-Labels-Button==============================================
textQues= Entry(abc1c, font= ('arial',18, 'bold'), bg='black',fg='white', bd= 2, width=50, justify= CENTER,textvariable= question1)
textQues.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, pady=4)

label_option1= Label(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), text='A: ', bg='black',fg='white', bd= 5, justify = CENTER)
label_option1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=4, sticky=W)
text_option1= Button(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), bg='blue',fg='white', bd= 5, width=17, height= 2, justify = CENTER, textvariable=choice1)
text_option1.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=4)


label_option2= Label(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), text='B: ', bg='black',fg='white', bd= 5, justify = CENTER)
label_option2.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=3, sticky=W)
text_option2= Button(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), bg='blue',fg='white', bd= 5, width=17, height= 2, justify = CENTER, textvariable=choice2)
text_option2.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)


label_option3= Label(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), text='C:', bg='black',fg='white', bd= 5, justify = CENTER)
label_option3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=4, sticky=W)
text_option3= Button(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), bg='blue',fg='white', bd= 5, width=17, height= 2, justify = CENTER, textvariable=choice3)
text_option3.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=4)


label_option4= Label(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), text='D: ', bg='black',fg='white', bd= 5, justify = CENTER)
label_option4.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=4, sticky=W)
text_option4= Button(abc1c, font= ('arial',14, 'bold'), bg='blue',fg='white', bd= 5, width=17, height= 2, justify = CENTER, textvariable= choice4)
text_option4.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=4)


raytxt=Label(abc2,font=('Cambri', 12, 'italic'), text='Built by: Raymond French ', bg='black', fg='white', bd= 5, justify= CENTER)
raytxt.grid(row=1, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it seems you don't know how GUI frameworks work - they have `mainloop` which run all time and does everything - it start to displaying window, gets mouse/keyborad events from system, sends events to widget, updates widgets, redraws window - all in loop which works all time. Every `if textQues == text_option4` before `mainloop()` are useless because they are executed before you see window. You have to put code in function and this function assign to button with `command=` and then it can be executed when window is already visible and you press button.

Comment: if you need help then create minimal working example so we could run it. Remove all images, sounds, fonts because we don't have it.

Comment: you could keep questions and answer on list (2-dimensional list) and creat only. You create new Buttons for new question - what if you will have 20 question or 100 question ? You code will be very long and many elements will be the same. Better use replace text in existing Button and it will works even if you will have 1000 question.

Comment: Hi Furas, yeah I'm still learning GUI.I've erased the images and sounds....

Comment: now you use `choice1.set(...)` four times before `mainloop` so last value will be used by `mainloop` - `choice1.set("32")` - and displayed with first question. At start you have to use only first `choice1.set('Mongoria')` - after first answer you will have to use `choice1.set("Green")` to set choice for second question. But you have to use `choice1.set("Green")` in function assigned to button.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep quetion, choices and correct answer on list. Later you can read data from file

This way don't have to create so many widgets. You can create widgets without text and use function which put/replace question and choices in widgets.

When you click answer it should run function which check if selected answer is correct. And then you can run again function which replace text in widget.

I create minimal working example only with important elements. And now code is much shorter.

```
import tkinter as tk


def set_question(number):
    global correct_answer

    row = all_questions[number]

    question.set(row[0])

    choice_a.set(row[1])
    choice_b.set(row[2])
    choice_c.set(row[3])
    choice_d.set(row[4])

    correct_answer = row[5]


def selected(selected_number):
    global current_question

    if selected_number != correct_answer:
        print('Game Over')
        root.destroy()
    else:
        current_question += 1
        if current_question >= len(all_questions):
            current_question = 0
        set_question(current_question)


all_questions = [
    #[question, choice_a, choice_b, choice_c, choice_d, correct_answer],
    ["What's the capital of Nigeria", 'Mongoria', 'Cairo', 'Accra', 'Abuja', 4],
    ["Which one of the color can be found in US National Flag", "Green", 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yelow', 2],
    ["What year is today", "2017", '2018', '2019', '2020', 3],
]

current_question = 0

root = tk.Tk()

top_frame = tk.Frame(root)
top_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

question = tk.StringVar()
choice_a = tk.StringVar()
choice_b = tk.StringVar()
choice_c = tk.StringVar()
choice_d = tk.StringVar()

# create Widgets for question and choices but without text
textQues = tk.Entry(top_frame, textvariable=question)
textQues.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)

label_option1 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='A:')
label_option1.grid(row=2, column=0)
text_option1 = tk.Button(top_frame, textvariable=choice_a, command=lambda:selected(1))
text_option1.grid(row=2, column=1)

label_option2 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='B:')
label_option2.grid(row=2, column=2)
text_option2 = tk.Button(top_frame, textvariable=choice_b, command=lambda:selected(2))
text_option2.grid(row=2, column=3)

label_option3 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='C:')
label_option3.grid(row=3, column=0)
text_option3 = tk.Button(top_frame, textvariable=choice_c, command=lambda:selected(3))
text_option3.grid(row=3, column=1)

label_option4 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='D:')
label_option4.grid(row=3, column=2)
text_option4 = tk.Button(top_frame, textvariable=choice_d, command=lambda:selected(4))
text_option4.grid(row=3, column=3)

# put first question in Widgets
set_question(current_question)

root.mainloop()
```

BTW: and use variable's names which means something - ie. `top_frame` instead of `abc`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please, can you look at my updated code once again? I've removed the images and sounds. I noticed that the first question appears on the entry widget but not the correct label option.

Comment: Hi furas, please check below to see the new challenge I have

Comment: stackoverflow is not forum. You have one place for question. Other places are only for answers/solutins. Don't put your question in palce for answer. If you have new problem then create new question on new page.